# tkinter: NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I've split my tkinter app in more file, and right now I've two file:

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

from login_info import LoginInfo 


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)        

        self.login_page = LoginInfo(self)
        self.login_page.pack(expand='True')     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

**login_page.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
class LoginInfo(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

       self.login_frame = tk.Frame(self)
       self.login_frame.pack()

       self.username_label = tk.Label(self.login_frame, text='Username:')
       self.username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

       self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_frame)
       self.username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

       self.password_label = tk.Label(self.login_frame, text='Password:')
       self.password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

       self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_frame)
       self.password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

       self.login_button = tk.Button(self.login_frame, text='Login', command=self.login)

       self.login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
       root.bind('<Return>', self.login)

   def login(self,event):
       print('Logged In')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = tk.Tk()
   LoginInfo(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
   root.mainloop()
```

In the login page I'm trying to bind the return button to a function but I'm gettin this error:

```
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

This happen only if I launch the code from main.py, if I launch it from login_page.py it works

Comment: What do you want to do on the line `root.bind('<Return>', self.login)`? When `login_page.py` is imported, `root` is not defined in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the duplicated ...

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = tk.Tk()
   LoginInfo(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
   root.mainloop()
```

... from the `login_page.py` and launch the code from `main.py`.

Use `if __name__ == '__main__':...` only once and only in the module which starts the program. Because only in this module the special variable [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) will have the value `'__main__'`.

Also, make sure that you import from `login_page`, not from `login_info` in the `main.py`, as you named that module `login_page.py` and not `login_info.py`.

#### Concrete code

I was able to get your example running by doing this:

```py
# main.py

import tkinter as tk

from login_page import LoginPage

class Main(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.login_page = LoginPage(self)
    self.login_page.pack(expand='True')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  main = Main(root)
  main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```

```py
# login_page.py

import tkinter as tk

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    
    self.login_frame = tk.Frame(self)
    self.login_frame.pack()
    
    self.username_label = tk.Label(self.login_frame, text='Username:')
    self.username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))
    
    self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_frame)
    self.username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))
    
    self.password_label = tk.Label(self.login_frame, text='Password:')
    self.password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))
    
    self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self.login_frame)
    self.password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))
    
    self.login_button = tk.Button(self.login_frame, text='Login', command=self.login)
    
    self.login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    
    self.bind_all('<Return>', self.login)

  def login(self, event=None):
    print('Logged In')
```

The trick is to use `self.bind_all` instead of `root.bind`, near the bottom of `login_page.py`, which binds the key to the whole application. This function seems not to be documented in the [official Python tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html), which may indicate that there is a more pythonic solution.

I personally would prefer to put the declaration of this binding in the main.py. We have a sub unit here, which silently modifies a parent unit. The bigger the project gets, the more this leads to problems.

Comment: Note that `self.login()` are used by `command` option of a button and `bind()`, so the `event` argument should be optional. Otherwise, when it is called by clicking the button, exception will be raised.

Comment: Just change `def login(self, event)` to `def login(self, event=None)` as long as `event` argument is not used inside the function.